# Unexpected values when assembling URL in ZF controller's action

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have named route for `admin/login/`

```
'adminLogin' => new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
        'admin/login/',
        array('controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'login', 'module' => 'admin')
),
```

Now let's take a look at controller where I'm calling Router's `assemble()` function:

```
class Admin_Controller_Index extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

    public function loginAction() {

        echo Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter()->assemble(
            array(
                'controller' => 'index',
                'action' => 'authentificate',
                'module' => 'admin'
            )
        );
        // will output /admin/login
        //any other plays with assemble() function will always return /admin/login
        //Why???
        exit;

    }

    public function authenitifcateAction() {
        echo Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter()->assemble(
            array(
                'controller' => 'index',
                'action' => 'authentificate',
                'module' => 'admin'
            )
        );
        //will output /admin/index/authentificate as expected
        //any other plays with assemble() function will aslo return expected values
        exit;
    }

}
```

So, `assemble()` will always return unexpected values if called in controller's action that have named route.

What am I doing wrong?